# How to enable wowza transcoder addon for Trial version

Tags: wowza, wowza-transcoder

I am trying to check wowza streaming engine(Trial) installed in local system and checking the feasibility of wowza live streaming application. Everything is working fine but unable to use transcoder add on. Please help me out with this concern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have one of the version 4 trial licenses, then it should allow you to use Transcoder for up to one channel (one incoming source). However, Transcoder does require the following in order to work:

1. Windows or Linux platform (MacOSX is not supported)
2. 64-bit OS architecture
3. If running on Windows servers, a minimum Windows Server 2008 R2 is required, the .NET Framework 3.5.1, and Desktop Experience.

Comment: I am using Wowza Streaming Engine Version 4.5.0 (build 18676) on Windows 7 32-bit OS, Is there any other alternatives for this OS ( 32-bit ) ?

Comment: You can look into transcoding externally (for example, using ffmpeg) and sending the multi-bitrate stream into Wowza. Note that these would need to be key-frame aligned.